# Add column to dataframe based on intervals from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a gpx file that I am manipulating. I would like to add a column to it that describes the terrain based on another dataframe that lists the terrain by distance.  Here are the dataframes:

GPS_df

```
    lat lon alt time    dist    total_dist
0   44.565335   -123.312517 85.314  2020-09-07 14:00:01 0.000000    0.000000
1   44.565336   -123.312528 85.311  2020-09-07 14:00:02 0.000547    0.000547
2   44.565335   -123.312551 85.302  2020-09-07 14:00:03 0.001137    0.001685
3   44.565332   -123.312591 85.287  2020-09-07 14:00:04 0.001985    0.003670
4   44.565331   -123.312637 85.270  2020-09-07 14:00:05 0.002272    0.005942
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
12481   44.565576   -123.316116 85.517  2020-09-07 17:28:14 0.002318    26.091324
12482   44.565559   -123.316072 85.587  2020-09-07 17:28:15 0.002469    26.093793
12483   44.565554   -123.316003 85.637  2020-09-07 17:28:16 0.003423    26.097217
12484   44.565535   -123.315966 85.697  2020-09-07 17:28:17 0.002249    26.099465
12485   44.565521   -123.315929 85.700  2020-09-07 17:28:18 0.002066    26.101532
```

terrain_df:

```
dist    terrain
0   0.0 Start
1   3.0 Road
2   5.0 Gravel
3   8.0 Trail-hard
4   12.0    Gravel
5   16.0    Trail-med
6   18.0    Road
7   22.0    Gravel
8   23.0    Trail-easy
9   26.2    Road
```

I have come up with the following code, that works, but I would like to make it more efficient by eliminating the looping:

```
GPS_df['terrain']=""
i=0
for j in range(0,len(GPS_df)):
    if GPS_df.total_dist[j]<= terrain_df.dist[i]:
        GPS_df.terrain[j]=terrain_df.terrain[i]
    else:
        i=i+1
        GPS_df.terrain[j]=terrain_df.terrain[i]
```

I have tried a half a dozen different ways, but none seem to work correctly. I am sure there is an easy way to do it, but I just don't have the skills and experience to figure it out so far, so I am looking for some help.  I tried using cut and add the labels, but cut requires unique labels.  I could use cut and then replace the generated intervals with labels in another way, but that doesn't seems like the best approach either.  I also tried this approach that I found from another question, but it filled the column with the first label only (I also am having trouble understanding how it works, so it makes it tough to troubleshoot).

```
bins = terrain_df['dist']
names = terrain_df['terrain']

d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))

GPS_df['terrain2'] = np.vectorize(d.get)(np.digitize(GPS_df['dist'], bins))
```

Appreciate any guidance that you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.merge_asof` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) between `GPS_df` and `terrain_df`?  Merging on `total_distance` and `dist` using `direction="backward"` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `pandas.merge_asof` should do the trick. Try:

```
result = pd.merge_asof(left=GPS_df, right=terrain_df, left_on='total_dist', right_on='dist', direction='backward')
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.  So many functions in pandas.